# Marketing Cloud Connect -- throwing Lightning errors at Configuration?

Tags: marketing-cloud, lightning, marketing-cloud-connect

I have been working on a Marketing Cloud integration and wanted to use the Cloud Connect Package.   I had it set up and working in a dev org, but now the app is not working.

What happens is that when I click the 'configure' tab, I get a modal overlay and there are a number of error messages below the page. These look like javascript or Lightning framework errors.

Checking the lightning inspector in chrome, I get this in the error tab:

```
 "failedAction": "et4ae5$message_modal$controller$setupModal",
"failedId": "b274a753-1031-4093-bade-159da4e41101",
"clientError": "Uncaught Action failed: et4ae5$message_modal$controller$setupModal [TypeError: Cannot read property 'opener' of undefined]\nthrows at https://mydomain.na22.visual.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:14743:7",
"clientStack": "    at wa (/resource/et4ae5__jQuery:5:18106)\n    at xa (/resource/et4ae5__jQuery:5:18248)\n    at Function.n.extend.css (/resource/et4ae5__jQuery:5:22501)\n    at Object.n.cssHooks.(anonymous function).get (/resource/et4ae5__jQuery:5:22702)\n    at Function.n.extend.css (/resource/et4ae5__jQuery:5:22473)\n    at /resource/et4ae5__jQuery:6:19875\n    at n.access (/resource/et4ae5__jQuery:4:30284)\n    at n.fn.(anonymous function) [as height] (/resource/et4ae5__jQuery:6:19646)\n    at et4ae5$message_modal.helper.centralize (components/et4ae5/message_modal.js:84:75)\n    at n.event.dispatch (/resource/et4ae5__jQuery:5:6466)
```

Any ideas?  Is this related to Summer 16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out this was due to Lightning Locker being enabled.  Disabling it solved the issue.